# My site dont have a http://, .htaccess not matching

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using http://htaccess.mwl.be/ to test out the htaccess file.

Rewrite link: http://mawek3.pro-linuxpl.com/de/test/ 
htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

`/test/` is just: `echo $_GET['lang'];`

The htaccess tester shows me that some rule is not meet if iam not using `http://` at the address and I'm still getting `lang=en` value.

When i add `http://` to website address(in httaccess tester) it works fine and displays "de".

The problem is that my webstie address don't display the http:// on the begining and rewriting method not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That htaccess tester requiring full URLs has nothing to do with Apaches mod_rewrite, which only works on request paths anyway. "Not working" is not a sufficient problem description, btw. Showcasing and concluding something from access+error+rewrite.logs would make more sense.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that this rule is not working
`RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]`

when iam going to http://mawek3.pro-linuxpl.com/de/test/ rule which is used is always `RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?lang=en [L,QSA]`

Comment: So you want to get begged for the RewriteLog a second time?